How to remove namespace from specific attribute?
This is my sample XML
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<DOCUMENT>
 <MY_DATA_SET xmlns="">
  <MY_DATA>
  <MY_DATA>
 </MY_DATA_SET>
<DOCUMENT>


I want to remove programmatically this part xmlns=""
output should be
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<DOCUMENT>
 <MY_DATA_SET>
  <MY_DATA>
  <MY_DATA>
 </MY_DATA_SET>
<DOCUMENT>

- let theDocument = getXmlNode(XML,'//DOCUMENT');
    (getXMLNode is a function it can give docuemnt node element)
- let testNode = create('<MY_DATA><MY_DATA></MY_DATA></MY_DATA>');   
    (create the XML from string)
- let firstChild = theDocument._domNode._firstChild;
    (getting the first child from the document)

theDocument.node.insertBefore(testNode.node._documentElement, firstChild);


output is :
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<DOCUMENT>
 <MY_DATA_SET xmlns="">
  <MY_DATA>
  <MY_DATA>
 </MY_DATA_SET>
<DOCUMENT>

I don want to see this part : xmlns=""
if i try to remove :testNode.node._documentElement.removeAttribute("xmlns");
it didn't work

Removing the namespace would potentially modify the meaning. I'm not sure if you can actually do this (without using string replace)

If you have well-formed XML like
<DOCUMENT>
 <MY_DATA_SET xmlns="">
  <MY_DATA>
  </MY_DATA>
 </MY_DATA_SET>
</DOCUMENT>

then, to get rid of the superfluous empty XML namespace declaration, it suffices to run the XML through an XSLT identity transformation, can be done with XSLT 3.0 and the XSLT code
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

and SaxonJS
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

const xml = `<DOCUMENT>
 <MY_DATA_SET xmlns="">
  <MY_DATA>
  </MY_DATA>
 </MY_DATA_SET>
</DOCUMENT>`;

const xslt = `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>`;

const serializedResult = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`transform(map{ 'source-node' : parse-xml($xml), 'stylesheet-text' : $xslt, 'delivery-format' : 'serialized' })?output`, null, { params : { xml : xml, xslt : xslt } });

console.log(serializedResult);

In the browser DOM/W3C DOM you should be able to use removeAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns') e.g.


const source = `<DOCUMENT>
 <MY_DATA_SET xmlns="">
  <MY_DATA>
  </MY_DATA>
 </MY_DATA_SET>
</DOCUMENT>
    `
    
const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(source, "application/xml")

xmlDoc.documentElement.firstElementChild.removeAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns');

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc));



I am not sure which DOM implementation you use with Node and whether it supports that removeAttributeNS method.

You can sort of "fake" the removal by creting a new namespace-free document and inserting into it the child data.
Note that both  your sample and expected xml are not well formed and the code below fixes that:


source = `<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<DOCUMENT>
 <MY_DATA_SET xmlns="">
  <MY_DATA/>
  <MY_DATA/>
 </MY_DATA_SET>
</DOCUMENT>
`
newdoc = `<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<DOCUMENT>
 <MY_DATA_SET> 
 </MY_DATA_SET>
</DOCUMENT>
`
domdocOld = new DOMParser().parseFromString(source, "text/xml")
domdocnew = new DOMParser().parseFromString(newdoc, "text/xml")

dest = domdocnew.evaluate('//MY_DATA_SET', domdocnew, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

newdat = `'<MY_DATA/><MY_DATA/>
    `
dest.snapshotItem(0).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newdat);

console.log(new window.XMLSerializer().serializeToString(domdocnew));



